# SQL Server stored procedure dynamic query (openquery) for a linked SQLite database returns errors

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, openquery, dynamicquery

I have SQL Server 2019 and have linked an SQLite database called [PSMDB_WIN_SVR] to it.

My objective is to retrieve data from the linked database for all records greater than or equal to a double variable parameter representing Julian Date/Time. The query runs fine in the native SQLite environment:

```
    SELECT julianDateUTC,
           frequency,
           Vrms, 
           I1rms,
           I2rms,
           I3rms,
           P1,
           P2, 
           P3,
           ProcessorTemp,
           Quality
    FROM tblRealTimeData
    WHERE  julianDateUTC >=  :JD
    ORDER BY julianDateUTC;
```

I have created the following dynamic stored procedure in SQL Server:

```
USE [pMonNetworkServer]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE getNewDataProc
    @jd VARCHAR(50)
AS
    DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(PSMDB_WIN_SVR, ' + 
               '' + 'SELECT julianDateUTC,
                     frequency,
                     Vrms, 
                     I1rms,
                     I2rms,
                     I3rms,
                     P1,
                     P2, 
                     P3,
                     ProcessorTemp,
                     Quality
            FROM tblRealTimeData
            WHERE  julianDateUTC >= ' + '' + @jd + '' + 
          ' ORDER BY julianDateUTC;' + '' + ')'
    EXEC (@sql)
GO
```

When I execute this using SSMS I get the following errors:

[Execution of Stored procedure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtTSW.png)

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 15
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Obviously my syntax is incorrect. The `OPENQUERY` SQL string has to be set in quotes as a literal and I am using '' for this.

I have also surrounded the `@jd` parameter in a single quote. I also tried without this, but I get the error whatever I do.

Can someone help with this please?

Comment: The way you debug dynamic SQL is replace `exec(@sql)` with `print(@sql)` at which point you have static SQL and its easy to debug. If you are still stuck at that point, then post the result of `print(@sql)` so we can assist.

Comment: This `+  '' +` does nothing useful. You are simply concatenating an empty string. You probably meant to use `+ '''' + ` (count those single quotes carefully). More importantly, you must actually SEE your query in order to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

The insertion of the ' delimiter by using + '' +  doesn't work.

The solution is to turn off delimeters and use + "'" +

I kind of suspected this, but because Microsoft removed debugging from SSLS 2019 duhhh! I installed 17 and confirmed the problem.

The correct code is

```
USE [pMonNetworkServer]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[getNewDataProc]    Script Date: 24/05/2020 13:13:14 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[getNewDataProc2]
@jd VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(PSMDB_WIN_SVR, ' +   
                "'" + 'SELECT julianDateUTC,
                     frequency,
                     Vrms, 
                     I1rms,
                     I2rms,
                     I3rms,
                     P1,
                     P2, 
                     P3,
                     ProcessorTemp,
                     Quality ' +
            ' FROM tblRealTimeData ' +
            ' WHERE  julianDateUTC >= ' + @jd +  
            ' ORDER BY julianDateUTC;' + "'" + ')'
END
EXEC (@sql)
```